# Parsing XML attribute with JQuery, keeps writing same attribute over and over instead of all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I'm trying to build two unordered lists through an AJAX call, referencing multiple member groups in an XML, and then writing to HTML via JQuery. Each member group has an  tag with a number that I'm adding as an attribute to the HTML that's being rendered. My problem is that it keeps repeating the last member group  tag in each LI that's being written instead of all of them in order.

I need the LI's to look like this:

```
    <li id="1">description 1</li>
    <li id="2">description 2</li>
    <li id="3">description 3</li>
    <li id="4">description 4</li>
```

instead they're looking like this:

```
    <li id="4">description 1</li>
    <li id="4">description 2</li>
    <li id="4">description 3</li>
    <li id="4">description 4</li>
```

The bulk of it can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/p9heB/

```
//THE PROBLEM HAS TO BE IN THIS PART RIGHT?
        $(this).find("id").each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).text();
        $('.thumbnails ul li a').attr('id', id);
        $('.bio ul li').attr('id', id); 
                });
```

Comment: can you show the entire rendered html.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://chunchmeow.com/users.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var $bio = $('.bio > ul');
            var $thumbnails = $('.thumbnails > ul');
            $(xml).find('member').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    id = $this.find('id').html();

                $('<li />', {
                    id: 'bio-' + id,
                    html: $this.find('bio').html()
                }).appendTo($bio);
                $('<li />', {
                    id: 'thumb-' + id,
                    html: '<a href="#">' + $this.find('photo').html() + '</a>'
                }).appendTo($thumbnails);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When you are setting the id at the end of the `member` loop instead of targeting a specific `li` you are targeting all `li` elements under `bio` and `thumbnails`.

Note: You are creating multiple elements with the same id, it is not valid as ID of an element must be unique in a page - add a prefix like `bio-` and `thumb-` for the `bio` and `thumbnails` ids respectively.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jy2Mf/)

Comment: holy moly that worked perfectly thank you!! I've been stuck for hours and it's been driving me insane! I also couldnt figure out how to globalize the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a selector to find the list elements where you want to put the id. You will be setting each id on every list element that exists at that time. When you are at the last item, it will overwrite the id of all previous items.

Keep a reference to the list items that you create:

```
var bioItem = $('<li>' + bio + '</li>').appendTo( ".bio > ul" );
```

and:

```
var photoItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + photo + '</a></li>').appendTo( ".thumbnails > ul" );
```

then use the references to set the id on those specific elements:

```
bioItem.attr('id', id);
photoItem.attr('id', id);
```

---

However, the id of an element should be unique in the page, so setting the same id on two elements is not advisable.

Also, using a numeric id can be problematic, you might want to add a prefix to the number, for example:

```
bioItem.attr('id', 'bio' + id);
photoItem.attr('id', 'photo' + id);
```